# How to perform event on next Fragment of viewpager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Suppose I am having 5 fragments in viewpager. Lets say Fragment A, B, C, D, E.

I have a button on fragment A to go to fragment B. When I press this button, viewpager scrolls to fragment B. Somehow I controlled the duration of fragment A to B. Now the thing is, I have an scrollable container in Fragment B. I want to scroll that container during the Scroll between A to B happens. Now its scrolling after I am going from Fragment A to B. I want this happen between this transition.

Inside first fragment:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId() == bottomLayout.getId())
    {

        MainActivity.pager.setCurrentItem(1);

    }
}
```

It will change my pager position 0 to 1. Now when its changing. I controlled the scroll speed of viewpager. On top of second fragment, I have a ScrollView, I need to perform scroll on this scrollview as fragment is changing,not after its changed.

Comment: You can use LocalBroadcastReceiver or other EventBus cause you don't have references for fragments in ViewPager.

Comment: I think you need to brief us how you're doing this transition from Fragment A to B. Are you using some sort of gestures? Thought about how you can disabling them in a meaningful way, such that the user doesn't find it unexpected?

Comment: I am doing it on button click. of fragment A. I have already written in question that I am using clicks.

Comment: When you're changing the fragment A to B, did you try calling `fragmentB.startScrollAnimation()` (where `startScrollAnimation()` is a method defined by you)?

Comment: I want animation inside view of fragment b. Not entire fragment I want to animate

Comment: Yes, the `startScrollAnimation()` will animate the ListView or ScrollView of your FragmentB.

Comment: How its possible before oncreateview is called

Comment: and I am calling viewpager.setCurrentItem on buttom click to change the fragment

Comment: @KhushalChouhan In your second fragment the scrollable view you are try to use is recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

To animate the view of the FragmentB, you need to tell it to start animation as soon as you call `viewPager.setCurrentItem()`.

1. Inside FragmentA's click listener, you will ask the parent Activity to change the ViewPager item (see [Communicating with the Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) to know how this should be done) :

   ```
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           activityCallback.setViewPagerItem(POSITION_OF_FRAGMENT_B);
       }
   });
   ```
2. In your Activity in which the `ViewPager` resides, you will write:

   ```
   public void setViewPagerItem(int position) {
       viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
       // following asks the fragmentB to start its animation on its view.
       if (position == POSITION_OF_FRAGMENT_B) {
           fragmentB.startYourAnimation();
       }
   }
   ```
3. In FragmentB, you add a method:

   ```
   public void startYourAnimation() {
       // write your code to animate your ListView or whatever you want to
       // animate inside the FragmentB
   }
   ```

**Notes:**

1. Unless you've called [`viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)), an instance of FragmentB will already exist if you're doing it from `FragmentA` or `FragmentC`,
2. a Fragment should not communicate with other fragments directly, instead they should use their parent Activity as a middle person. See [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Comment: If there's a problem with above solution, let me know.

Comment: How to get fragmentB instance in fragmentA . By traditional Method Or we have any method in viewpager adapter

Comment: The view on which I want to perform animation returns null in startAniamtion because view is initialized in onCreateView

Comment: I updated the answer. Please make sure you aren't calling `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit()` anywhere. Also check that you're following the updated answer. If it still doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118212/discussion-between-khushal-chouhan-and-sufian).

Comment: Different from what I suggested? What type of error? Please elaborate. Lets continue in the chat - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118212/discussion-between-khushal-chouhan-and-sufian

Answer (score -1):

No it is not possible to do so because any scrollable view like listview or recyclerview, the items are created only when it is visible to user and only when scrolled, so if that fragment is not visible, you cannot scroll any of its child scrollable view.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without view pager?

Comment: No the thing you require, doesn't relate to viewpager.

Comment: thats what I am asking that is there any way to do this without view pager.

Comment: The best way is using it with viewpager only.